# Overriding rake tasks and rake task dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rake, circular-dependency, rake-task, rakefile

I'm using a build system which defines a number of rake targets, including this one:

```
task :test => [:all]
```

This seems incorrect to me, and so I defined my own rake tasks like so:

```
task :test => [:spec]
task :all => [:test, :build]
task :release => [:all]
task :default => [:release]
```

However, now I'm getting this error when I try to build my package:

```
Circular dependency detected: TOP => default => all => test => all
Tasks: TOP => default => all => test
BUILD FAILED
```

I've come to realize that defining a rake task (or dependencies for a rake task) just **appends** those tasks/dependencies to the task definition!  This is driving me crazy!  Why can't I redefine my rake tasks as I see fit?!  Is there any way to overwrite a rake task, and/or to overwrite the dependencies of a rake task?

Comment: I found this post from 2008, but it seems like such a hack! There must be a cleaner way to do this, right? http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/rake-task-overwriting.html

Answer (score 6):

Use this before you define your task:

```
Rake::Task[:test].clear
```

This is implemented in the rake gem, file lib/rake/task.rb
You can see it also supports *clear_prerequisites*, *clear_actions*, *clear_comments*, *clear_args* as well (*clear* does all four things).

Comment: This answer truly helped me. Especially mentioning the additional methods. This is very useful to use in the `Rakefile`.